# Display data from database into the tableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I am trying to display some data from a database into a TableView(JavaFX).

Update: 
    This is my ControllerClass:

```
public class CustomersController implements Initializable   {
    @FXML
    private static TableView<Customers> tableView;
    @FXML
    private static TableColumn customerIDCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customers, String> firstName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customers, String> lastName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customers, String> address;
    @FXML
    private Button addButton;
    @FXML
    private Button addRemove;
    @FXML
    private Button addUpdate;
    @FXML
    private TextField searchBar;
    @FXML
    private Button goButton;
    @FXML
    private Button bookButton;
    @FXML
    private ObservableList<Customers> data;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stat;
    private PreparedStatement prep;
    Database db = Database.getInstance();
    ResultSet rs = null;    

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try{
           String sql = "SELECT * FROM FRUITS ";
           rs = db.query(sql);
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/customers/fruits.db");
           stat = con.createStatement();
           while(rs.next()){
               Customers cn = new Customers();
               cn.firstName.set(rs.getString("FirstName"));
               data.add(cn);

               System.out.println(rs.getString("FirstName"));

           }
           firstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));

           tableView.setItems(data);
           tableView.getColumns().add(firstName); 
       }
       catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();;
           System.out.println("error");
       }    
    }    

    @FXML
    private void handleAddButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    }

}
```

Is printing the firstName in the console but it gave me an error on tableView.setItems(data);

```
private static TableView<Customers> tableView;
private TableColumn<Customers, String> firstName;
```

Setters/Getters

```
 public  SimpleStringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();

 public String getFirstName() {
     return firstName.get();
 }
 public void setFirstName(String firstNameStr) {
     firstName.set(firstNameStr);
 }
```

The error in the console is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at customers.CustomersController.initialize(CustomersController.java:98)
```

line 98 is the tableView.setItems(data);

Comment: at first remove `data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` from cycle

Comment: nothing changed, same error.

Comment: Are you able to print out the value of `data` before the `table.setItems(data)` ?

Comment: Please **DO NOT** deface your question. This is a question and answer site, not a help site, and in this situation, the quality of the question is paramount. If you deface the question such that the answer doesn't make as much sense, you ruin the value of the question for future visitors.

Comment: As bad as defacing your own question is, defacing an answer of someone else is even worse. Don't do that.

Comment: @Adriaan: indeed! Answer edit rolled back. Mike -- why are you doing these things?

Comment: Rolled back again -- again Mike, why are you continually defacing your question?

Answer (score 1):

Customers.java

```
public class Customers{
    public  SimpleIntegerProperty customerID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public  SimpleStringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public  SimpleStringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public  SimpleStringProperty address = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public  SimpleStringProperty customerType = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public  SimpleStringProperty phone = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public  SimpleStringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public int getCustomerID() {
        return this.customerID.get();
     }
    public void setCustomerID(int id) {
          this.customerID.set(id);
     }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
     }
    public void setFirstName(String firstNameStr) {
          firstName.set(firstNameStr);
     }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
     }
    public void setLastName(String lastNameStr) {
          lastName.set(lastNameStr);
     }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address.get();
     }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
          this.address.set(address);
     }
    public void setCustomerType(String type) {
          this.customerType.set(type);
     }

    public String getCustomerType() {
        return this.customerType.get();
     }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
          this.phone.set(phone);
     }
    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone.get();
     }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
         this.email.set(email);
     }
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email.get();
     }

}
```

Conrtoller class

```
public class CustomersController implements Initializable   {
    @FXML
    private static TableView<Customers> tableView;
    @FXML
    private static TableColumn<Customers, int> customerIDCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customers, String> firstName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customers, String> lastName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Customers, String> CustomerType;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    private ObservableList<Customers> data;
    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stat;
    private PreparedStatement prep;
    Database db = Database.getInstance();
    ResultSet rs = null;


    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
       try{

           while(rs.next()){
               data.add(new Customers(
                    rs.getInt("CustomerID"),
                    rs.getString("FirstName"),
                    rs.getString("LastName"),
                    rs.getString("CustomerType"),
                    rs.getString("Address"),
                    rs.getString("Phone"),
                    rs.getString("Email")
               ));
           }
           CustomerIDCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("customerID"));
           firstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
           lastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));
           CustomerType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("customerTpe"));
           address.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("address"));
           phone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("phone"));
           email.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("email"));

           tableView.setItems(data);             

       }catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();;
           System.out.println("error");
       }

    }    

    @FXML
    private void handleAddButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{


        }

    }

}
```

FXML CODE

```
 <children>
            <TableView id="tableView" fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="272.0" prefWidth="887.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn id="CustomerIDCol" fx:id="customerIDCol" prefWidth="130.0" text="CustomerID" />
                <TableColumn id="firstName" fx:id="firstName" prefWidth="130.0" text="FirstName" />
                  <TableColumn id="lastName" fx:id="lastName" prefWidth="130.0" text="LastName" />
                  <TableColumn id="CustomerType" fx:id="CustomerType" prefWidth="130.0" text="CustomerType" />
                  <TableColumn id="address" fx:id="address" prefWidth="130.0" text="Address" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="phone" prefWidth="130.0" text="Phone" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="email" prefWidth="110.0" text="Email" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
         </children>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135461/discussion-on-answer-by-shekkar-raee-display-data-from-database-into-the-tablevi).